# MVC select editor view model with ddl and quantities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I've been using this good solution in the past to managing multiple selected items on a view:

http://johnatten.com/2014/01/05/asp-net-mvc-display-an-html-table-with-checkboxes-to-select-row-items/

Now i have a similar problem and i think this approach could help. My model has an order table, that match lot of products. On a Create view i want to add products to my order with a DDL with Product and an input for Quantities. These works whith an add item buttom and a modal:

[Add buttom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwWmZ.png)

[The modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gUoy.png)

ViewModels:

```
public class SelectProductEditorViewModel
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public Models.Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class CreateOrderViewModel
{
    public CreateOrderViewModel()
    {
        this.Products = new List<SelectProductEditorViewModel>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<long> getSelectedProductIds()
    {
        return (from p in this.Products where p.Quantity > 0 select p.ProductId).ToList();
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> getSelectedProductQuantities()
    {
        return (from p in this.Products where p.Quantity > 0 select p.Quantity).ToList();
    }
    public List<SelectProductEditorViewModel> Products { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ProductList { get; set; }

}
```

Is posible to implement this using that approach? (i'd tried other solutions using JS and works, but i think that using viewmodels and native MVC tools is a better way to resolve this...)

Comment: **Is possible to implement this using that approach?** which approach ?

Comment: http://johnatten.com/2014/01/05/asp-net-mvc-display-an-html-table-with-checkboxes-to-select-row-items/ this one